# In Skyrim does SetEssential on companions or anything mess up the game??

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I want to set my companions as SetEssential with the console.. that way they cant die.. will anything bad happen if I do that??

Answer (score 5):

Nope, as a rule, setting a "non-essential NPC" as "essential" won't mess anything up. Since followers are all non-essential, you can set them as essential. Except for one quest where you have to sacrifice a follower (Boethiah), which won't work if this follower is essential, obviously.

But don't, I repeat, DON'T set an "essential NPC" as "non-essential", which can greatly mess the game.

Comment: Not unless you find it fun to kill essential NPCs off. :)

Comment: Ulfric took it in the face quite a few times, yes.. But one should never do it without saving first, and then loading the game, since game with a dead essential is essentially screwed ("To continue the main quest, bring this axe to Ulfric!" "Oh, well... About that...")